# Can AWS EMR cluster resolves JFrog Artifactory jar packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifactory, amazon-emr, jfrog-cli

I am spinning up AWS EMR cluster and passing some packages ins --packages argument including some custom packages that I've created in JFrog Artifactory and obviously cluster job is not able to resolve JFrog Artifactory packages. So is there any way to resolve those packages in AWS EMR cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EMR bootstrap actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) to install packages from Artifactory.
Amazon has a bunch of [examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-bootstrap-actions) of such bootstrap actions, some of them shows how to resolve packages in various formats (for example Yum). There is also an [example](https://gist.github.com/cosmincatalin/866233457e28ecb9224b126cd2747cb5) of how to use CRAN to resolve R packages during bootstrap.